# filtering members based on the age using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to check for people in a certain age range. I have two ComboBoxes, minagecombobox and maxagecombobox, with values between 1 and 120.

I want to get the people whose age is between these two values (suppose for example I want to filter out the people aged between 18 and 24).

This is the Member table structure:

```
     member_id 
     member_firstname 
     member_dob(datatype is string) (values like 1987-09-08,1976-09-08,.....)
```

i am using mysql as my database.....

```
**Modified query** 


             SELECT members.member_Id,
                   members.member_Lastname as 'Last Name',
                   members.member_Firstname as 'First Name',
                   members.member_Postcode as 'Post Code',
                   members.member_Reference as Reference,
                   members.member_CardNum as 'Card Number',
                   members.member_IsBiometric as Biometric,
                   members.member_DOB as DoB,
                   mshiptypes.mshipType_Name as Membership,
                   mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Name as Status,
                   membertomships.memberToMship_EndDate as Expiry
                     FROM members
    INNER JOIN membertomships ON membertomships.member_Id = members.member_Id
     INNER JOIN mshipoptions ON mshipoptions.mshipOption_Id = membertomships.mshipOption_Id
    INNER JOIN mshiptypes ON mshiptypes.mshipType_Id = mshipoptions.mshipType_Id
    INNER JOIN mshipstatustypes ON mshipStatusTypes.mshipStatusType_Id = membertomships.mshipStatusType_Id
    WHERE memberToMship_EndDate BETWEEN '2011-09-24' AND '2011-09-30'
    AND members.member_active LIKE 'y%'
    AND (YEAR(CURDATE(members.member_Dob))-YEAR()) - (RIGHT(CURDATE(),5)< RIGHT(member_Dob,5)) BETWEEN '21' AND '102'
    ORDER BY members.member_Lastname
```

got an error like this.....

```
     Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'member_Dob))-YEAR()) - (RIGHT(CURDATE(),5)< RIGHT(member_Dob,5)) BETWEEN '21' AN' at line 19
```

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: What are you using to display the UI / combo boxes? PHP, ASP .NET, WinForms, something else...? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: You're losing me with the combo boxes. Do you simply want to select people from the current database who fall between certain ages? Or what are you trying to do? Combo boxes aren't mySQL, they are whatever language you are using to interact with the database. Please clarify.

Comment: @Yuck: The combo boxes are a red herring IMHO - they don't have any bearing on the question.

Comment: @Yuck  pls see my modified query i got an error

Comment: @digitaltoday   pls see my modified query i got an error

Comment: @errorcode105: It even **tells you** where the error is. Is it too much to look up `CURDATE()` in the reference? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM MEMBER
WHERE (YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(member_dob)) - (RIGHT(CURDATE(),5)<RIGHT(member_dob,5)) 
BETWEEN 18 AND 24
```

The WHERE clause has the age calculation formula. Get the number of years by subtracting the year of birth from current year and then further subtract 1 if one current day and month is less than the day and month of DOB. In case, you get a datatype mismatch error, use `STR_TO_DATE(member_dob, '%Y-%M-%d')` to convert the string DOB to DATETIME DOB.

Comment: Note that with all the string and date manipulation going on, this query will be painfully slow on anything > 100k rows.

Comment: @Piskvor Agreed. In which case OP should convert 'minage' and 'maxage' into actual dates first and then use those two dates in the query.

Comment: You have used `YEAR(CURDATE(members.member_Dob))-YEAR()` but I have mentioned `YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(members.member_dob)`, please fix your query.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do. Your question doesn't make much sense since combo boxes aren't mySQL, they are whatever language you are using to interact with the database. You would be better programmatically determining the date range and passing the dynamic variables to mySQL, but here is a concept for now. Also, why is member_dob a string? Make it a datetime....

```
SELECT * FROM Member 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(member_dob, '%Y-%M-%d') BETWEEN '1900-0916' AND CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way:

```
SELECT * FROM MEMBER
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, members.member_dob, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 18 AND 24
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactor so that `member_dob` is of type `DATE` (or another date-related datatype), then use `SELECT member_id, member_firstname, member_dob FROM Member WHERE member_dob BETWEEN '1993-09-16' AND '1987-09-16'` (note that 1993==2011-18 , 1987==2011-24 , month and day are from today).

You'll need to convert the date of birth to some sort of date anyway - this approach allows you to use the database for data *searching*, something it's pretty good at (instead of just using it as a data *store*).